# Magento - change multiselect semantics from "or" to "and"

Tags: mysql, magento

When more than one value of a multiselect is used as a filter on a catalog or catalogsearch page in Magento, the multiple values are or'd together - i.e. the result is the union of the products that have any of these attributes.

How would I get the intersection of the sets of products with the selected attributes - i.e. only those products that have all of the selected attributes?

Comment: Are you using an extension for filtering on multiple values of one attribute? I don't seem to have that functionality in magento default settings?

Comment: Truth is, I am using Amnasty's Shopby for filters.  I had thought that what I'm asking was a built-in dynamic, but now you have me wondering.  I'm going back to dig...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard behavior of Magento you can only filter for one value like Lucasmus already indicated.
So you seem to be using some customization or module which edits the behavior of the core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php model.
Also the class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Layer_Filter_Attribute has to be rewritten, this is exactly the class where you could change the behavior you asked for.
In that class, the method

`applyFilterToCollection($filter,$value)`

creates the corresponding SQL code to do the filtering.
Currently your module or extension probably uses an OR notation, or uses something like

`$connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.value IN (?)", $value)`,

so it searches for any of your to be filtered values.
To achieve an AND, you will have to rewrite this method by splitting the $value into its distinct parts and using a where clause for each of the individual values.
Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You're right.  The Amnasty module has rewritten it.  A good answer to  a not-so-good question.  Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to include signature in your post - your user card is added automatically. Read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) for more details.